# How do I ignore a directory (/dir/) with .gitignore but keep an identically named subdirectory (/other/dir/)?

Tags: git

I have a directory entitled `dir` in the top directory of an app i'm working on that I'd like to ignore. As such, I have included `dir/` in my `.gitignore` file. However, in another folder, I have a different directory called `dir` (specifically, `other/dir/`). How can I go about ignoring the top level `dir` without ignoring the subdirectory?

Would a `!other/dir/` do the trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like that?

```
/dir/
```

It should then only ignore the `dir` folder that is at the root.

Comment: oh nice! i tried `./dir/` previously. yay removing the dot seems to have worked!!!

Comment: You might want to accept the answer if it worked for you :) Thanks

Comment: yeah stackoverflow has some delay before you can accept it - didn't let me do it the first couple times i tried. :)